# Integrating a hosted app with wordpress using the API

Tags: plugins, api

Say I have a hosted application that I want to tightly integrate with Wordpress to do the following:

1. An admin logs into WP, then clicks on a link and redirects to my website.  How can I have this user automatically log into my application?
2. Once the user is logged in using single-signon, can I currently using the existing built-in API access all the content, users, categories in users WP installation?  Is this read-only or I can also read/write?

I know there are plugins, but I don't really see any hosted app's that integrate with WP.  I'm not saying they don't exist, I just havent' seen them so I am wondering if it is possible to do with how things are built-in currently.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about doing this kind of thing is to add some settings to the plugin they are installing such as the following:

- (Blankman's Site - Your User Name)
- (Blankman's Site - Your Password)
- (Blankman's Site - User Name to access your site)
- (Blankman's Site - Password to access your site)

The user could then add in the first two values and, if set, they could be used to automatically log them in when they click the link to your site before actually directing them there, most likely via javascript, curl, etc.

Then, if they set the user name and password for your site to access their site, you could encode / encrypt it and transfer it to your site during their log in, unencode / decrypt it, and store the credentials somewhere for use in accessing their site.

Of course, they would have to create a user account on your site and give you a set of permissions.

This would a clean, up front method of doing it.